# combine objects in an array based on one attribute

Tags: java

I have an object array, say for example `Animal[4]` elements. In my end result I need to prepare another `Animal` array, say for e.g. `Animal[2]`. Can anyone please suggest how to merge attributes of the objects to a unique object based on a single attribute like `type`.

For e.g.:

```
public class Animal {
    private String type;    
    private boolean isWild,
    private Boolean isCarnivarous;
}
```

Object array values:

My First Object Data Animal :  `{type: XXX, isWild: true, isCarni: false}`
My second Object Data Animal : `{type: YYY, isWild: true, isCarni: false}`
My third Object Data Animal :   `{type: XXX, isWild: false, isCarni: true}`
My fourth Object Data Animal : `{type: zzz, isWild: false, isCarni: true}`

End result should be:

My First Object Data Animal : `{type: XXX, isWild: true, isCarni: true}`
My second Object Data Animal :  `{type: YYY, isWild: true, isCarni: false}`
My third Object Data Animal : `{type: zzz, isWild: false, isCarni: true}`

Comment: That is strange. Why does `isCarni` overwrite the old value, but `isWild` does not? (for type *XXX*)

Comment: I don't understand the second object data in the end result. what is "isenter code herewild"

Comment: anyway I suggest you use HashTable instead of an array.

Comment: @user2397162 `isenter code herewild` was an error in the formatting.

Comment: As @Tom comments, it is not clear whether you want to keep your first XXX animal or override it with the 2nd one. Do you need to mix/mutate values?

Comment: Actually I don't want to override,I want to create unique animal with type as the key attribute and get all the Boolean variables which are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you need the various boolean properties to merge using OR semantics. Is that right?

If so, loop through your arrays and place the objects into a `Map<String, Animal>`, where the key is the `type`. This will de-dupe the animal entries with the same type.

But before you put each value in, check if a value already exists and mutate the boolean properties accordingly.

Comment: I got your second point that we need to put in a Hashmap.               I assume you need the various boolean properties to merge using OR semantics. - you are right. Can you please let me know how to achieve it

Comment: If the result includes `{type: XXX, isWild: true, isCarni: true}`, then this is a merger of the two XXX inputs. If `isWild` is true in *either* input values, then it must be true in the result. Same with `isCarni`. Going by the provided result, you can't simply overwrite the existing value in the map, you need to change it by comparing both old and new values.